# Remove object array items by comparing object array from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

There is document which is having array of object inside.
Like

```
Objectid('')
  fruits : [{_id:'2'},{_id:'3'},{_id:'4'}]
```

I want to delete these items `fruits_id = [{_id:'3'},{_id:'4'}].`

```
fruit_group.updateOne(
         {collection_id: collection_id},
        {$pullAll: {"fruits":  fruits_id}}
     )
```

so far i found below logic which i think is not efficient.

```
routes.post('/removeFruits', async (request, response, next) => {
    var post_data = request.body;
    var collection_id = post_data.collection_id;
    var  fruits_ids = JSON.parse(post_data.fruits_ids);
    var prev_fruits;

await fruit_group.findOne({'collection_id': collection_id}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console("Some error occurred");
        response.json({'message': "Some error occurred", 'result': 'false'});
    }
    prev_fruits = result.fruits;

});

for (var i = 0; i < fruits_ids.length; i++) { // this will delete all occurring items from array 
    var key = fruits_ids[i].user_id;
    prev_fruits.filter(x => x.user_id === key).forEach(x => prev_fruits.splice(prev_fruits.indexOf(x), 1));
}

await fruit_group.updateOne({'collection_id': collection_id}, {$set: {'fruits': prev_fruits}}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        response.json({'message': "Some error occurred", 'result': 'false'});
    }
    response.json({'message': 'Deletion successfully', 'result': 'true'});
});

});
```

is there anyway to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fruits_id = [{ _id: '3' }, { _id: '4' }]`, you could do something like this using [`$pull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
await fruit_group.updateOne({'collection_id': collection_id}, { $pull: { fruits: { $in: fruits_id }}})
```

This follows the example of [removing all items that equal a specified value](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-all-items-that-equal-a-specified-value).